# HTML Links in Android List View

Tags: android, html, listview, hyperlink, android-listview

I have a custom listview in android, with each item consisting of several text views. One of the text views contains HTML text, some of which contains `<a>` tags. I am using the `HTML.fromHTML()` method to translate this into a `String` readable by the `textView`, but the links are not clickable. If I enable them to have focus, then the list items are no longer clickable and the links still do not work.

So how do I make the links clickable, and keep the normal click functionality if a list item is clicked anywhere other than on a link?

EDIT: My code:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.email_list_item, null);
    }


    TextView contentView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.content);

    Email e = items.get(position);

    CharSequence content = "";
    if (e.getContent() != null) {
        content = Html.fromHtml(e.getContent());
    }

    contentView.setText(content);
    return convertView;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set AutoLinkMask

```
textcontent.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.get_text()));
textcontent.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: This stops the list items themselves being clickable, I still want them to hear the click event if it isnt a link being clicked.

Comment: Added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom list view row add this line in XML.

List row XML:

```
android:autoLink="web"
 android:linksClickable="true"
```

But its display list view text as an HTML tag like below :

```
<a href= "http://google.com">Google </a>
```

If i add the Html.fromHtml(text) inside that then links are no more clickable.